# Torah only given to share with others?

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, kabbalat-hatorah

Where do Chazal say that Hashem gave the Torah to Klal Yisroel *not* for ourselves as individuals to learn rather to understand and give over to others?

Comment: "Maharsha in his commentary (Sanhedrin 99b) suggests that "adam le-amel yulad" (People are born to work,") le-amel is an acronym for "Lilmod al menat le-lamed" - to study and master in order to share and teach to others." - https://www.torahweb.org/torah/1999/moadim/ryud_shavuos.html ?

Comment: אם למדת תורה הרבה, אל תחזיק טובה לעצמך, כי לכך נוצרת

Comment: I do not see how that Mishnah deals with what op was asking for tbh. The Mefarshim, specifically R'Yona explain that we were created to do G-ds will. I did not see anyone saying that we need to learn and give it to others.

Comment: @shmuel There’s a drush-y read of the mishnah: אל תחזיק טובה לעצמך - don’t keep the good Torah that you have learned to yourself, rather share it with others, as that is what you were created for.

Comment: @JoelK Ah Okay. I did not know that tbh.